# Deducing a curve from torsion and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like an example of how to get a curve, $\alpha$, from torsion, $\tau(s)$, and curvature, $\kappa(s)$.

Lets say I have $\tau(s) = \kappa(s) = s^2$.

A curve with this torsion and curvature exists, but I want to find it.

I understand we have a system of ODEs in the frenet frame,

$T'(s) = \kappa(s)N(s) = s^2N(s)$

$N'(s) = -\kappa(s)T(s) + \tau(s)B(s) = -s^2T(s) + s^2B(s)$

$B'(S) = -\tau(s)N(s) = -s^2N(s)$

We can assume $T(0)=T_0, N(0)=N_0, B(0)=B_0$

What I don't understand is how we get our curve $\alpha$ with soley this information and nothing of what $T(s), N(s), B(s)$ are.

Maybe we do this,

Since $\alpha'(s) = T(s)$

$N'(s) = s^2T(s) + s^2B(s) <=> T(s) = \frac{1}{s^2}N'(s) - B(s)$

$\int T(s)ds = \int \frac{1}{s^2}N'(s) - B(s) ds$

$\alpha(s) = \frac{1}{s^2}N_0 - \int B(s)ds$

Help is appreciated. There are similar questions on SE, but none are very useful to me and people may benefit from an example.

Comment: For your example, note that $T+B$ is constant, so $T-B$ (and $N$) spins in the orthogonal plane and you missed the minus sign on $N'=-\kappa T+\tau B$.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it. And I'm not sure what you mean. $T(s)$ and $B(s)$ are both functions of s and I don't understand why their sum would be constant. Also what do you mean $T-B$ spin in the orthogonal plane?

Comment: You should have $N'(s)=-s^2T+s^2B$ instead of $s^2T+s^2B$.  Anyway, since both $T-B$ and $N$ are orthogonal to $T+B$ they are orthogonal basis of $(T+B)^\perp$ and hence rotate in that plane for all $s$.  The only remaining point is to determine how they rotate in the plane and finally integrate $T$.  See my answer below.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. $T- B$ and $N$ are orthogonal to $T+B$, because $T-B \cdot T+B = 0$ and $T$ and $B$ lie in the $TB-$ plane so $N$ is orthogonal to all the vectors in the plane. Therefore they can form an orthogonal basis of $(T+B)^{\perp}$. And I'll read the part below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly quickly, the Frenet-Serret formulae
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\begin{bmatrix}T\\N\\B\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}0&\kappa&0\\-\kappa&0&\tau\\0&-\tau&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}T\\N\\B\end{bmatrix}
$$
For general $\kappa,\tau$ this differential equation doesn't have "nice" solutions.  But in your case note that $\kappa=\tau$ means $T+B$ is constant, so we reduce to solving
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}(T-B)\\N\end{bmatrix}
&=\begin{bmatrix}0&(\kappa+\tau)/\sqrt2\\-(\kappa+\tau)/\sqrt2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}(T-B)\\N\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}0&\sqrt2s^2\\-\sqrt2s^2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}(T-B)\\N\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac1{\sqrt2}(T-B)&=\cos(\theta(s))\frac1{\sqrt2}(T_0-B_0)+\sin(\theta(s))N_0\\
N&=\cos(\theta(s))N_0-\sin(\theta(s))\frac1{\sqrt2}(T_0-B_0)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
with $\theta'(s)=\sqrt2 s^2$ and $\theta(0)=0$, i.e., $\theta(s)=\frac{\sqrt2}3s^3$.  So
$$\begin{aligned}
T(s)&=\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}(T+B)+\frac1{\sqrt2}(T-B)}{\sqrt2}\\
&=\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}(T_0+B_0)+\cos(\theta(s))\frac1{\sqrt2}(T_0-B_0)+\sin(\theta(s))N_0}{\sqrt2}\\
&=\frac{1+\cos\frac{\sqrt2}3s^3}2T_0+\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin\frac{\sqrt2}3s^3 N_0+\frac{1-\cos\frac{\sqrt2}3s^3}2B_0
\end{aligned}
$$
But then $\exp(\lambda z^3)$ doesn't have elementary antiderivatives (for nonzero $\lambda$), so unless you want to have [confluent hypergeometric function $_{1}F_{1}$] or suchlike you can only write
$$
\alpha(s)=
\alpha(0)+T_0\int_0^s\frac{1+\cos\frac{\sqrt2}3\sigma^3}2\,\mathrm{d}\sigma+N_0\int_0^s\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin\frac{\sqrt2}3\sigma^3\,\mathrm{d}\sigma+B_0\int_0^s\frac{1-\cos\frac{\sqrt2}3\sigma^3}2\,\mathrm{d}\sigma.
$$

Comment: Why do we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(T+B)?$

Comment: Also this answer is a bit complicated for me, is there no way to get an easier to understand curve with this information. For instance aren't circular helixes the only curves with constant curvature and torsion?

Comment: Also how do you get the $2 \times 2$ matrix from the $3 \times 3$

Comment: Exercise for you: $\frac1{\sqrt2}(T+B),\frac1{\sqrt2}(T-B),N$ is an orthonormal frame.

Comment: $(T+B), (T-B), N$ is an orthonormal frame (I can take the euclidean product of any two of the vectors and it will be orthogonal, then by construction of T,N,B its will be orthonormal), and scaling by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ won't change that. But I don't understand why you wouldn't choose $(T+B), (T-B), N$. Also reducing down to a $2 \times 2 $ matrix is still unclear

Comment: $T+B,T-B,N$ is only orthogonal, not orthonormal.  We choose $(T+B)/\sqrt2$ to be a member because we know it is constant, so you just need to deal with the other two.

Comment: My mistake. I understand why, $T+B,T-B,N $ is not orthonormal. Can you explain how you get the 2x2 matrix?